# SQL Server reporting services administrative access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssrs

I have a server which has SQL server reporting services installed within it and I need to give permission to a user to administer reporting services/have the content manager role.

I however I did not install SQL reporting services on this machine and I'm not 100% on who did.

Is there a way for a full server administrator/domain admin to assign permissions to others in reporting services and if so how as I seemingly don't have permissions to the permissions tab on http://servername/reports

Thanks in advance,
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default SSRS appears to have BUILTIN\Administrators group as site administrators and little else. This doesn't appear to include domain admins either.

To gain access I suggest logging into the box using the local administrator account and you should find you have access. Once in then add any appropriate administrative groups.

See also [Lesson 1: Setting System-Level Permissions on a Report Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337385.aspx)